# dropdown selected on page load angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is a dropdown :

```
  <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Role</label>
                                    <select ng-model="User_Role" class="dropdown form-control" ng-options="t.RoleName for t in rollist track by t.ID">
                                        <option value="" >-- Choose Role --</option>
                                    </select>


                                </div>
                            </div>
```

the dropdown bind here:

```
 $scope.rolelist = function () {
    var role = UserService.getroleInfo();
    role.then(function (d) {
        //debugger;
        $scope.rollist = d.data;


    }, function (err) {
        //debugger;
        alert("Some Error Occured ");
    });
}
```

how do selected the dropdown dynamic value in angularjs??

here is the dynamic dropdown `<option label="Admin" value="1" >Admin</option>`

can any one tell me how do i selected when page load using angular

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your success call back :)

```
$scope.rollist = d.data;
$scope.User_Role=$scope.rollist[0]; // or $scope.User_Role=$scope.rollist[0].RoleName
```

Comment: @asasasaa What is not working?  Did you getting any error? My code should be set a value for your dropdown on load.

Comment: here i want to bind the dynamic value on whatever the value comes in dynamic

Comment: Prprty.then(function (response) { $scope.User_Role = response.data.RoleID

Comment: You have an array so you can do it like `response.data.RoleID` it should like `response.data[0].RoleID`

Answer (score 0):

here I used direct return in service instead of that you can use your http request in service

```js
    var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
    app.service('UserService',function(){
      this.getroleInfo=function(){
          return [{ID:1,RoleName:"Admin"},{ID:2,RoleName:"User"}];
      };
    });
    app.controller('testCtrl',['$scope','UserService',function($scope,UserService){

    /*+role.then(function (d) {
        //debugger;
        $scope.rollist = d.data;


    }, function (err) {
        //debugger;
        alert("Some Error Occured ");
    });*/

     //place this below code in inside of your role.then(function(){})
     $scope.rollist= UserService.getroleInfo();
     $scope.User_Role={ID:2,RoleName:"User"};//here place your dynamic data

    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">

<div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Role</label>
          <select ng-model="User_Role" class="dropdown form-control" ng-options="t.RoleName for t in rollist track by t.ID">
              <option value="" >-- Choose Role --</option>
          </select>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-init in the div and call a function that sets the ng-model value. for example: `ng-init="assignValue()"`, and in the controller:

```
$scope.assignValue = function(){
    $scope.User_Role = $scope.rollist[0]
    }
```